# unable to access value of JSON array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In my javascript I am trying to read values from a JSON file from a server.  The file contains a array of objects but I cannot access the values in these objects. When I try this my log says the value is undefined. However, when I try to stringify a Object in the array it works perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong?

The JSON file:

```
{
  "NETWORKS": [
    {
      "NETWORK": {
        "STARTDATE": "00:13:33:15:10:2015",
        "SSID": "Ziggo323_AC",
        "WPA": "YES",
        "WEP": "NO",
        "WPS": "YES",
        "OPEN": "NO",
        "WPATEST": {
          "DURATION": "3000",
          "DATE": "00:11:26:24:09:2015",
          "ATTEMPTS": "594",
          "STATUS": "FAILED"
        },
        "WPSTEST": {
          "DURATION": "2932",
          "DATE": "03:11:28:24:09:2015",
          "ATTEMPTS": "9",
          "STATUS": "PASSED"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "NETWORK1": {
        "STARTDATE": "00:15:26:15:10:2015",
        "SSID": "FreeWiFi",
        "WPA": "NO",
        "WEP": "NO",
        "WPS": "NO",
        "OPEN": "YES"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The javascript function

```
function LoadTestResults() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'GetJSON.php',
    data: "TestResults.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      var wpsDuration = data.NETWORKS[0];
      console.log(JSON.stringify(wpsDuration)); // output ={"NETWORK":{"STARTDATE":"00:13:33:15:10:2015" etc.
      console.log(wpsDuration.WPA); // output = undefined
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: i think you need to access it like  console.log(wpsDuration.NETWORK.WPA) instead of console.log(wpsDuration.WPA);

Answer (score 2):

Just try with:

```
wpsDuration.NETWORK.WPA
```

or with a loop:

```
for (var k in data.NETWORKS) {
  var network = data.NETWORKS[k];
  var networkKey = Object.keys(network).pop();

  console.log(networkKey, network[networkKey].WPA);
}
```

Comment: That works thank you. But I want the function to be dynamical. If there are many networks (like network1, network 2) I want to be able to access them like NETWORKS[x]. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Loop through them and give them out for each.

Comment: So you have to loop this `wpsDuration` object. Check my edit.

Comment: I have tried but it only gives me the value of the NETWORK and not NETWORK1. The console gives the output: NETWORK YES

Comment: @RikSmits You're right - I see the problem. Check my answer now.

Comment: @hsz Thank you. Your solution works. Can you explain why it has to be done this way? What does Object.keys(network).pop()?

Comment: `network` object contain nested object with SOME key that we do not know (NETWORK, NETWORK1). With `Object.keys(network)` we get those key and since it returns an array with one element, we `pop` it from this array into a `networkKey` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `debugger;` before this line `var wpsDuration = data.NETWORKS[0];` and inspect the `data`.

> Keep your console open while debugging. Once the success will reach
>   debugger will hit.
>
> then move to console window and try different combinations. This will
>   help you to understand your object.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it worked for me

Put a debugger; before this line var wpsDuration = data.NETWORKS[0]; and inspect the data

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?